# Object string representation in Python/IPython shell

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode, ipython

I have a friendly month class I enjoy that returns an ugly robot friendly string:

```
In [3]: d = date(2010, 1, 31)

In [4]: m = Month(d)

In [5]: m
Out[5]: <dfa.date_range.Month at 0x7fb4d5793cc0>
```

I want `m` to show something like `1-31-2010`. I try using `unicode` and `str`, just like in django, no dice:

```
class Month(object):

    def __init__(self, dateobj):
        self.dateobj = dateobj

    # def __unicode__(self):
    #     return self.dateobj

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dateobj

    @property
    def first_day(self):
        return self.dateobj.replace(day = 1)

    @property
    def last_day(self):
        _, days_in_month = monthrange(self.dateobj.year, self.dateobj.month)
        return self.dateobj.replace(day = days_in_month)

    def date_range(self):
        return self.first_day, self.last_day
```

For `d` object, it doesn't implement unicode, but has string. The `str` and ipython return don't match. I'll open a separate question for that. How can I make my python classes display something useful for the user? Terima kasih

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *real* issue is that both Python 3 shell and IPython call `repr` *NOT* `str` on your object. Here's a snippet to play with to see:

```
In [1]: class Car(object):
   ...:     def __str__(self):
   ...:         return 'car str'
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return 'car repr'
   ...:     

In [2]: car = Car()

In [3]: car
Out[3]: car repr
```

Without the `__repr__` defined, IPython would simply output something along `<__main__.Car at 0x7f05841b1350>` instead of falling back to `__str__`.

Unless you e.g. explicitly call `str(car)` or `print(car)`, in which the `__str__` will be used.

So, you should define a [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) in the object.

> What purpose is `__str__` nowadays then?

It's not that `__repr__` replaces `__str__` in Python 3 or anything, but `__str__` merely returns a readable reprentation of the object, while `__repr__` is a more complete unambiguous representation (to the point where you can even reconstruct the object from the `__repr__` output)

Comment: ty, what purpose is __str__ nowadays then?

Answer (score -2):

I believe you could change Month's **str** to this:

```
def __str__(self):
  return self.dateobj.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

so it would access the date object and output it with the format you want
Edit: Also, as already posted, you can make the **repr** method and just make it point to the **str** so you always get the same format

Comment: Hi, I believe `__str__` on a class in IPython is _not_ enough, because without `__repr__`,  IPython simply prints somehting like: `<__main__.MyClass at 0x7f05841b1350>`

Answer (score -2):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.dateobj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

though you could already output the date object's details by `d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: I don't think so, see my answer to try it out.