# what method determines ipython return, it isn't str or unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, ipython, python-3.4

these don't match, the return of `6` and `8`...notice there is no unicode, in ipython using python3:

```
In [2]: from datetime import date

In [3]: d = date(2010, 1, 31)

In [6]: d
Out[6]: datetime.date(2010, 1, 31)

In [7]: d.__
d.__add__           d.__eq__            d.__hash__          d.__new__           d.__rsub__          d.__subclasshook__
d.__class__         d.__format__        d.__init__          d.__radd__          d.__setattr__       
d.__delattr__       d.__ge__            d.__le__            d.__reduce__        d.__sizeof__        
d.__dir__           d.__getattribute__  d.__lt__            d.__reduce_ex__     d.__str__           
d.__doc__           d.__gt__            d.__ne__            d.__repr__          d.__sub__           


In [7]: d.__str__
Out[7]: <method-wrapper '__str__' of datetime.date object at 0x7fb4d5733f30>

In [8]: d.__str__()
Out[8]: '2010-01-31'

In [9]: type(d)
Out[9]: datetime.date

In [10]: d.__class__
Out[10]: datetime.date
```

`9` and `10` also don't match. How does ipython get `datetime.date(2010, 1, 31)`
, is that an ipython thing I shouldn't worry about? Thank you

Comment: Did you try `repr()` ?

Comment: no I just learned on another post it seems repr is what you want for normal objects. I got thrown off because I'm used to `__str__`, then `__unicode__` in django

Comment: @codyc4321 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295601/object-string-representation-in-python-ipython-shell/35295678#35295678

Answer (score 2):

ipython uses the `repr()` function, that calls method `__repr__()` :

```
In [1]: from datetime import date

In [2]: d = date(2010, 1, 31)

In [3]: print(repr(d))
datetime.date(2010, 1, 31)
```